# CoreData - Refreshing an object doesn't change registeredObjects count

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'd like to free some memory releasing unused ManagedObjects from the context.

I prefer not to use `reset` and I want to release single objects using this function:

```
[self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:alarm mergeChanges:NO];
```

Now, if I log the `registeredObjects count` after this call it seems that nothing has changed. I still get the same number of objects that I have before the call.

Just to help you understand the example here it's a simple description of the model:
It is a typical Task list with Reminders. So there are Task objects and Alarm objects related to those tasks. Any task can have more than one alarm.

And here is the code that generates this problem:

```
 Alarm *alarm = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_ALARM inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.task.alarm = [NSSet setWithObject:alarm];

    [self saveContext];

    [self.managedObjectContext refreshObject:alarm mergeChanges:NO];
```

Since I'm in a detail view for the `Task` I'm not interested in maintaining in memory the `Alarm` object.

**My questions are:**

**1)** Why the count of registered objects doesn't change after calling `refreshObject`

**2)** Is this a good practice? Or should I go with reset, avoiding to release single objects?

Comment: you only fault the object, so it should stay registered, but its data was faulted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the count of registered objects doesn't change after calling refreshObject

Because you aren't deleting it, you're just turning the object into a fault (so its details are removed from memory but not disk).

> Is this a good practice? Or should I go with reset, avoiding to release single objects?

Reset destroys the in-memory representation of all of the objects in the context - you generally don't want to do that. Refreshing leaves the object as valid, just a fault. Refreshing means you need to drop all references to any objects in that context as they are invalid and can't be used again (you would need to refetch).

Generally, refreshing is a good approach, but only if you need to keep a reference to the object and aren't likely to need the object details very often. If you don't need the object then you should release it instead.

Comment: can I remove just a single object from the MOC instead of refreshing?

Comment: Removing from the MOC is deleting, faulting the memory is refreshing - you need to be clear what you're trying to do, remove from disk (delete) or just from RAM (refresh).

Comment: I meant to refresh the memory. My previous comment refers to your last sentence "If you don't need the object then you should release it instead."

Comment: Releasing the object is like refreshing, but you don't call refresh, you just nil your reference to the managed object instance and Core Data will clean the memory for you